# PHP can anyone explain this var dump

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This var dump is returned when results are found, why would it be throwing an error if it is finding results.

```
object(DB)#3 (5) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(80) "SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE `name` = ? AND `act_date` = ? AND `time_from` = ?" } ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (7) { ["activity_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["name"]=> string(7) "Archery" ["act_date"]=> string(10) "12/01/2015" ["time_from"]=> string(5) "10.00" ["time_to"]=> string(5) "11.00" ["num_people"]=> string(2) "12" ["booking_id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#8 (7) { ["activity_id"]=> string(2) "13" ["name"]=> string(7) "Archery" ["act_date"]=> string(10) "12/01/2015" ["time_from"]=> string(5) "10.00" ["time_to"]=> string(5) "11.00" ["num_people"]=> string(2) "10" ["booking_id"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#9 (7) { ["activity_id"]=> string(2) "56" ["name"]=> string(7) "Archery" ["act_date"]=> string(10) "12/01/2015" ["time_from"]=> string(5) "10.00" ["time_to"]=> string(5) "11.00" ["num_people"]=> string(2) "10" ["booking_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(3) }
```

This var dump is returned when the query cannot find any results:

```
object(DB)#3 (5) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(80) "SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE `name` = ? AND `act_date` = ? AND `time_from` = ?" } ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(0) { } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(0) }
```

The query is called:

```
!$activity->checkDateTimeAvailability($act_name, $act_date, $time_from)

// Method to check if the activity is available at the requested date and time.
public function checkDateTimeAvailability($act_name, $act_date, $time_from) {
    $fields = array($act_name, $act_date, $time_from);
    $result = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE `name` = ? AND `act_date` = ?
    AND `time_from` = ?", $fields);

    var_dump($result);
    if(!empty($result)){
        echo "query successful";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The DB Query Method:

```
// Generic query method.
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    // reset to ensure an error from a previous query is not returned. 
    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();

        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
            echo 'Error: ', $this->_error;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that error happens?

Comment: I really can't work that out, I wonder is it to do with the private _pdo object. I don't think there should be an error as the query runs. I tried to print the error out to screen but it doesn't work. The query returns results in MySQL. Can you suggest other ways for debugging?

Comment: What error is being returned?

Comment: ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) can't work out the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this code works pretty fine.

First you save link to the `DB` object to `$result` variable, then you use `var_dump` and there should be a message "query successful" and `checkDateTimeAvailability` function will always return `true` to the calling side.

Probably, you should get query result from DB object or selected rows count. `!empty($result)` will always be true, because `$result` - is object, not array of data, fetched from query.

## EDITED

You have serveral opportunities:
First
Look up DB class, where `query` method described and look for methods like `Count()` or `GetResult()`. If such methods exists - use them.

    `if ($result->count() > 0){
        echo "query successful";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }`

Second
If there is no such methods in `DB` class, and this is not some library class you can add your own realisation of Count method

`public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }`

It would be much easier, if i could see all DB class.

Comment: Thank you so it is always going to return true. How would I go about changing the code then, so that if the object returned null it would send false back?

Comment: go to answer. deleted